# Changes to PWA manifest not applying

Tags: html, progressive-web-apps

I'm having trouble applying updates made to Progressive Web App manifest. Updating stuff works otherwise just fine, but if I change something from my manifest, like background_color, the launch screen color will not change. I have monitored my server to see that manifest.json is indeed fetched. Restarting phone doesn't apply the changes either, the only way seems to be to uninstall the PWA and add back to home screen.

On desktop, chrome developer tools show that the manifest is correctly fetched and the changes can be seen in the dev tools. Is this expected behavior? Is there a way to make changes to manifest apply after the PWA has already been installed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has been addressed in the official [The Web App Manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#test) docs:

> **Note**: If you update your manifest.json file in the future, those
>   changes won't be automatically picked up by the users unless they
>   re-add your app to their home screen.

So, this is indeed the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks seems like I missed it. I did see the SO post, but the answer is completely opposite of what you're saying, so it didn't help.

Comment: Looks like the quoted section has been removed from the linked Google page.

Comment: still have the problem

Comment: removing the app and re-adding it still shows the original mannifest